# Dynamic forms and wrapped Angular Material form controls

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm creating a component library based on Angular Material v11. I decided to wrap Material controls to add custom styling and simplify the api. I created a wrapper for the Input and implemented a ControlValueAccessor interface to make it work with dynamic forms. Works well. Then tried almost the same with Radio, but I can't make it pass the selected value to the form object. I noticed that $event.value (radio.component, line 10) passed to the wrapped control is always empty, but couldnt figure out why.

Here's the current code. I provided also unwrapped Material controls for comparison.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-wrapping-components-myt1ef

What should be done to make my Radio component work with dynamic forms?

Comment: Can't open the link. Are sure it's working for non-signed users?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience and thanks @TsvetanGanev The link is fixed.